# swift 5 - predicate where date is this year

Tags: swift

I saved in core data date values like this (attribute saveDate):

```
2020-11-09 06:12:17 +0000
```

Now I would like to get all Data, where the year of the date is the current year (2020)
My first try is this direction:

```
let date = Date()
let currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date)
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "saveDate == %@", currentYear)
```

But this doesn't work logically.
But how can I realize the "predicate situation" ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the start date of this year, and the start date of next year, and check if the date is between them:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentYear = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: Date())
let startOfThisYear = calendar.date(from: currentYear)!
let nextYear = DateComponents(year: currentYear.year! + 1)
let startOfNextYear = calendar.date(from: nextYear)!

// create the predicate like this:
NSPredicate(format: "saveDate >= %@ AND saveDate < %@", argumentArray: [startOfThisYear, startOfNextYear])
```

Comment: ah okay, I understood ! Thanks :)

Comment: To get the start and end dates, it's also possible to use `calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: date)` - this returns an optional `DateInterval` which, when unwrapped, will give you `start` and `end` values.